# Why is epsilon not a rational number?

Tags: rational-numbers, surreal-numbers

I was wondering why epsilon, the smallest positive number, isn't a rational number. I was watching a video a few days ago about surreal numbers, and I've learned that, in the field of surreal numbers, o.(9) is not equal to 1, in contrast to the field of the real numbers, where they represent the same number. In the field of surreal numbers, you would get epsilon by subtracting 0,(9) from 1. If you were to do this in the rationals, you would just get 0. But I think there is a method do get epsilon even in the rationals, you would just take the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n {1\over 10^i}$$
Am I making a wrong mathematical assumption or...? Is there a reason for which epsilon couldn't be a rational number?

Comment: The value of your limit is $0$.

Comment: Although in your case it's $0$, the limit of a sequence of rational numbers is not necessarily rational! Consider $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, \ldots$, with a limit of $\pi$.

Comment: @Aphotesis What does 'rational' mean in the context of surreal numbers?

Comment: Does that limit even exist in the surreal numbers (at least in the order topology)? If we take $\varepsilon=\{0|1,\frac{1}2,\frac{1}4,\ldots\}$ then if $\varepsilon'=\{\varepsilon|1,\frac{1}2,\frac{1}4,\ldots\}$, the interval $(0,\varepsilon')$ contains $\varepsilon$, but no term of the sequence.

Comment: The rationals are a subset of the reals which are a subset of the class the surreal numbers.

Comment: There is no clear way to give sense to $0.(9)$ in the surreals so the video you watched probably just stated $1-\varepsilon$ was this number because $1 - \varepsilon = \{0;0.9;0.99;...\} \ | \ \{1\}$ but this is just a convention.

Comment: $\epsilon=\frac{1}{\omega}$ is not the smallest positive number in the surreals or the hyperreals.  For example, $\frac{1}{\omega+1}$ is smaller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Surreal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Infinity) :

> Consider the smallest positive number in $S_ω$:
>
> > $\varepsilon =\{S_{-}\cup S_{0}|S_{+}\}=\{0|1,{\tfrac {1}{2}},{\tfrac {1}{4}},{\tfrac {1}{8}},...\}=\{0|y\in S_{*}:y>0\}$.
>
> This number is larger than zero but less than all positive dyadic fractions. It is therefore an infinitesimal number, often labeled $ε$.

Thus *epsilon* is, "by definition" less than (and so different from) all rational in the $(0,1)$ interval.

Comment: This however, is not in the $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise we would have a contradiction. Right?

Comment: @AndresMejia What contradiction?

Comment: And it surely isn't *the smallest positive number*.

Comment: Then it all depends on what we're talking about, right?

Comment: @AndresMejia: Yes, it's not in $\Bbb R$, it is in the field of *surreal* numbers, as the OP clearly mentions.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was wondering. @SimpleArt: suppose that $\epsilon>0$. Then by archimedean property, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$... By the same argument, there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt(2)}$, but then $q\sqrt(2)<\epsilon$, meaning that there is always some irrational number between zero and epsilon.

Comment: @AndresMejia The surreal numbers are not archimedean.

Comment: I know, I was simply saying that *if* it were in $\mathbb{R}$, there would be a contradiction. I apologize for the confusion, I'm not well versed in the field of surreal numbers. I was simply making sure. Thanks

Comment: @AndresMejia No problem.  Stuff can get really confusing when you learn so many things.

Comment: How is this the smallest positive surreal number? The surreal numbers form a field, so should it be true that $\epsilon/2 < \epsilon$?

Comment: @ASKASK Instead, maybe $\epsilon/2 = \epsilon$. Zero satisfies a similar relation, $0/2 = 0$,

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen every field is an integral domain, so if $ \epsilon \cdot \frac12 \epsilon $, then $-\frac12 \cdot \epsilon = 0$ , so either $-\frac12 =0$ or $\epsilon =0$, and I highly doubt both of those

Comment: @ASKASK You are right, of course!! And now I read a bit on the linked Wikipedia page, and $S_\omega$ does not designate _all_ surreal numbers, and $S_\omega$ is just a "step" in the process of constructing all the surreal numbers. In particular $S_\omega$ is not a field. So as _egreg_ commented, this $\epsilon$ is not "the smallest positive number" (which cannot exist). It _is_ the smallest positive number in $S_\omega$, I believe. Also, your comment shows that _no_ ordered field can have a least positive element.

Comment: @egreg: While the surreal numbers are not archimedean, they are "ordinal-archimedean": For every surreal number, there exists an ordinal number that is larger. And thus for any positive surreal $r$, there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $1/\alpha < r$.

Comment: @celtschk Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are assuming that "multiplying infinitely many rational numbers yields a rational number," and this is not necessarily true. Doing things "infinitely many times" (really, taking a limit of a process) is a pretty good way to leave the rationals, even when we stay within the realm of real numbers.

Every (nonnegative) decimal number you can write down is a sum of rational numbers of the form $\frac{d}{10^n}$, where $d$ is an integer between $0$ and $9$, and $n$ is some integer. So, for example,

$$\pi = \frac{3}{10^0} + \frac{1}{10^1} + \frac{4}{10^2} + \frac{1}{10^3} + \ldots,$$

but $\pi$ certainly isn't rational, despite being the sum of infinitely many rational numbers.

For products, we can use [Euler's product formula for the Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula) to write

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \left( \frac{1}{1 - 2^{-2}} \right)\left( \frac{1}{1 - 3^{-2}} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1 - 5^{-2}} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1 - 7^{-2}} \right) \cdot \ldots$$

a clearly irrational number as a product of infinitely many rational numbers, although the value of $\pi^2/6$ is highly nontrivial.

Comment: The OP works with surreal, not with real numbers, and here things are a little bit different. (Yours is the fourth answer under which I post this comment.)

Comment: I know it doesn't yield a rational number necessarily, but when I'm looking at that limit, for me it resembles epsilon, an infinity of zeroes and, somehow, a 1 at the end.

Comment: I do understand, @AlexM. , I was merely pointing out one mathematical assumption I thought I identified. I know essentially nothing *about* surreal numbers, so perhaps my comment is not worth anything here. If I accrue enough downvotes, I'll take that to be the case :)

Comment: "The OP works with surreal, not with real numbers"  Which is not relevant.  The reals can be considered a subset of the surreals and the rationals of subset of the reals.  Neither the reals nor the rationals have a smallest positive number.  So if the surreals do, it can not be rational.

Comment: "The OP works with surreal, not with real numbers"  Wrong.  The OP is asking about rational nuumbers which are real.  His question is "why isn't epsilon rational".  Well, it's not rational because it isn't real.  And to explain why it isn't real we pretty much have to talk about real numbers, don't we?

Comment: "I know it doesn't yield a rational number necessarily, but when I'm looking at that limit, for me it resembles epsilon, an infinity of zeroes and, somehow, a 1 at the end"  well, that answers your question, doesn't it?  Such a number doesn't exist in the rationals.  Such a number is equal to 0 in the reals.  Such a number could exist and be positive in the surreals but that is the only place it could.

Answer (score -6):

Okay.  I do not know much about the surreal numbers.  So I looked on wikipedia and these were the *VERY FIRST* two sentences.

"In mathematics, the surreal number system is an arithmetic continuum containing the real numbers as well as infinite and infinitesimal numbers, respectively larger or smaller in absolute value than any positive real number. The surreals share many properties with the reals, including a total order ≤ and the usual arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division); as such, they form an ordered field."

This answers why epsilon, the smallest positive (surreal) number, can not be rational.  The rational numbers and the real numbers have the archimedian property that between any two rationals and between any two reals there exist a third.  So it is impossible to have a smallest positive real or rational number.  So if a smallest positive number is possible (as apparently it is) it can not be real or rational otherwise it would be the smallest real or rational number which is impossible.

So, I interpret the OP question to be why doesn't his construction of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n\frac 1{10^i} $ produce a least rational number?

Because the lim = 0.  (It also needn't be rational {although it is}.  But it does need to be real-- and there is no least positive real either.)

=====

Okay, I wasn't aware that epsilon exists in the field of surreal numbers and does have a definition as the smallest positive surreal number (I guess).

But here, fundamentally, the surreals are not the reals.  The rationals are the rationals and as $0 < 1/(n+1) < 1/n$ there can be no smallest positive rationals.  Thus any system that allows a smallest positive number (which the reals do not), such a number can not be rational.

=====================

<strike>1) epsilon is *not* the smallest positive number.  epsilon is not a set number at all.  It is a variable to represent possible numbers.  It is no more or less a number than, x, n, or i are numbers for exactly the same reasons and in exactly the same way.</strike>

2) There is no smallest positive |*real*| number.  This is fundamental to <strike>mathematics</strike> *real analysis*. [ed: and so any smallest positive number can not be real.]

3) The limit of a sequence (or sum) of rational numbers need not be rational at all.  Indeed it is a fundamental principal of *real* [ed: emphasis added later] numbers that *all* real [ed: but not surreal] numbers  (rational *and* irrationals) are limits of sequences of rational numbers.

4) The limit of the infinite product you gave is 0.

Comment: The OP works with *surreal*, not with real numbers, and here things are a little bit different. (Yours is the third answer under which I post this comment - the other two got deleted by their authors.)

Comment: The OP is asking about *rational* numbers.  Which *are* real.  The smallest positive surreal number is possible but it most certainly is neither rational nor real.

Comment: The OP asks about a surreal number being rational or not.

Comment: And this particular surreal number is not rational.  It's not rational because it is the smallest positive number.  Such a number can not possibly be rational nor even real.  To explain why it can not be rational I DO have to talk about real numbers

Comment: *"Such a number can not possibly be rational nor even real."* Of course, it's surreal, and it obeys other, sometimes surprising and counterintuitive rules than real numbers.

Comment: All of which has *nothing* to do with the OP question "why can't the smallest positive be rational?"