# How can a Cauchy sequence converge to an irrational number?

Tags: limits, infinity, irrational-numbers, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I am a physics major and would like to clear a confusion regarding complete metric spaces. I am quoting the definition of a Cauchy sequence from wikipedia below

> Formally, given a metric space $(X, d)$, a sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$
>   is Cauchy, if for every positive real number $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all positive integers $m, n > N$, the distance
>
> $$d(x_m, x_n) < \epsilon$$

Now, if we have sequence like $x_1=3, x_2=3.1, x_3=3.14, \ldots$ converging to $\pi$, I do not understand how all distances $d(x_m, x_n)$ will be less than all positive real numbers. Since irrational numbers do not terminate and continue forever, how can the distance ever be less than the smallest real number or infinitesimal (hyperreal) as the distance can never become $0$. Does this definition of completeness apply where $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal (hypperreal) ?

Kindly excuse my ignorance as I am not a mathematics major.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think of it as one particular distance, $d(x_m,x_n)$, is smaller than every positive real number. But rather, any given positive real number, you can go far enough out to guarantee that $d(x_m,x_n)$ is smaller.

Comment: There is no "smallest [positive] real number".

Comment: It is not that the distance is smaller than *every* positive real number, it is that for *any* positive real number, there is a point where the distance is eventually less than it.   E.g. can you eventually go far enough that the sequence is accurate to the fifth decimal place? (i.e. $\epsilon=10^{-5}$)  Can you go far enough that the sequence is accurate to the hundredth decimal place?  (i.e. $\epsilon=10^{-100}$)  If I were to give you some number of decimal places, could your sequence eventually be that accurate?  The answer of course is yes.

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I understand your feeling. OP is confused, and maybe we can help him achieve understanding of the concept. But try to abstract the situation, and look solely at the question itself. First of all, there is no question. Second, he says he "does not understand (...)", which is not what he is supposed to understand, since what he states after that is not the definition. Third, the next phrase also doesn't make sense. Okay, so we can explain the concept of a Cauchy sequence. What then? What is the question we are supposed to answer, after addressing that issue?

Comment: @MichaelHardy My opinion is: this question is obviously not off-topic. However, it is unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo : Perhaps it is unclear to you, but not to me. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Of both my comments, you responded to the one that marks an *opinion*, but not to the one that talks about three *facts* which are often used as means to consider a question "unclear" (note that the parts I mentioned correspond to the entire relevant body of the question: the rest is referential information). It seems to me that this is a case of empathy, not of procedural application of the site's standards. Well, I think there is no use for discussion: you are apparently adamant about your opinion, and so am I. I voted to close, you didn't. It is simple.

Comment: Hyperreals are pretty much irrelevant to this. (Well, they're kind of related, but you don't need to know anything about them for this.)

Comment: The criterion for being a Cauchy sequence doesn't require that "all the distances" be less than some positive number. But if $x_1=3,x_2=3.1,x_3=3.14,\dots$ and $n,m>N$ then $d(x_n,d_m)<10^{-N}$. So pick $N$ large enough so that $10^{-N}<\epsilon$ and you are done for any $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The subject line currently reads “How can a Cauchy Sequence converge to an irrational number?”.

If we construe that literally, then one easy way a Cauchy sequence (lower-case initial "s") can converge to $\pi$ is that every term of the Cauchy sequence is $\pi$.  Thus: $x_1=\pi, x_2=\pi, x_3=\pi,\ldots\,{}$.  I suspect you meant “How can a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers converge to an irrational number?”.

Consider your sequence $3,\ 3.1,\ 3.14,\ 3.141,\ \ldots\,$.

The definition DOES NOT say that all distances between members of this sequence are less than all positive numbers.  That would happen only with a constant sequence like my first example above.  It says:

> For every positive real number $\varepsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all positive integers $m,n>N$ we have $d(x_m,x_n)<\varepsilon$.

Notice that $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$.  In fact as $\varepsilon$ gets smaller, typically $N$ must get bigger.  Suppose $\varepsilon = 0.01$.  Then for your example sequence, $N=3$ is big enough: every pair of numbers in the sequence at or after the third place in the sequence differ from each other by less than $\varepsilon=0.01$.  Thus $3.14$ and $3.141$ differ by less than $0.01$.  But now suppose $\varepsilon=0.00001$.  Then you need a bigger value of $N$.  If each term of the sequence has one more digit or $\pi$, then $N=5$ would be big enough for that value of $\varepsilon$.

Notice that the definition of convergence to $\pi$ differs from the definition of "Cauchy sequence".  It says for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that for every positive integer $n\ge N$ we have $|x_n-\pi|<\varepsilon$.  Again, $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$.  If $\varepsilon=0.00001$, then $N=5$ would be enough: every term at or beyond the $5$th one differs from $\pi$ by less than $\varepsilon=0.00001$.

There is nothing in either of these definitions that says that the distance between two different members of the sequence or the distance between $\pi$ and a member of the sequence is $0$.

You wrote:

> Since irrational numbers do not terminate and continue forever

Let's be clear on a definition.

It is certainly not correct that numbers whose decimal expansions do not terminate are necessarily irrational.  For example, $1/7 = 0.\ 142857\  142857\  142857\ \ldots$ has a non-terminating decimal expansion and is rational.

Nor is it the case that "rational number" is defined as one whose decimal expansion repeats or terminates.  Euclid and other ancient Greeks proved some numbers are irrational without ever thinking about decimal expansions.  That $\pi$ is irrational means $\pi$ is not a quotient of two integers, like $22/7$.  Proving $\pi$ is irrational is so difficult that it was not done until the 18th century.  Some numbers are far easier to prove to be irrational.  For example, if $\log_2 3 = m/n$ and $m,n$ are positive integers, then $2^m=3^n$, but that can't happen because an even number cannot be equal to an odd number.

The fact that a number is rational if and only if its decimal expansion repeats or terminates takes a bit of work to prove, but it's elementary enough that high-school students will understand it.

Comment: In the last sentence, I think you meant "...a number is _rational_ if and only if its decimal expansion repeats or terminates..."

Comment: I think my confusion is kind of clear....you choose $\epsilon$ first and then $N$. I do not have a mathematician's temperament for rigor so I do sometimes miss subtle ideas.  But, does this definition work with hyperreals.  I mean what if $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal. $N$ will go to infinity in that situation. So how does that work ? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the section after the quoted statement "Since [the decimal expansions of] irrational numbers do not terminate and continue forever." You appear to be trying to rebut that statement, but the statement is true. The asker never claims that numbers whose decimal expansions don't terminate are rational. They also don't claim that the definition of being rational is that the decimal expansion repeats or terminates. Both of those claims would be false but they're never made so I don't understand why you're rebutting them.

Comment: Agree with @DavidRicherby; this answer would be improved by taking out the rebuttal that infinite decimals are necessarily irrational, which was never part of the OP's inquiry.

Comment: Er, I mean the asker doesn't ever claim that non-terminating decimals are _irrational_. Doh!

Comment: @phd-applicant : With hyperreals, you would say that if $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal but not $0$, whenever $n,m$ are infinite integers, then $d(x_n,x_m)$ is infinitesimal. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @phd-applicant There are infinite hyperreals as well as infinitesimal ones. If $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal hyperreal, $N$ would be an infinite hyperreal in this case.

Comment: The first two paragraphs are nothing more than pointless pedantry.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : Why would you say that?  If someone is learning this subject, they should become aware of things like that.  "Cauchy sequence" is not defined as meaning a Cauchy sequence of _rational_ numbers. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 7):

It's not the case that "all distances $d(x_m, x_n)$ will be smaller than every real number". That is not even true "eventually", in the sense that  for some $N$, it's true for all $m, n > N$. That would imply that all such distances are $0$. Furthermore, of course there is no "smallest [positive] real number". The point is that for *any* positive real number $\epsilon$, no matter how small, the distances between the terms of the sequence eventually get smaller than $\epsilon$ *and stay smaller* than $\epsilon$.

Think of it as a challenge: I give you some $\epsilon>0$, and you have to find a position in the sequence (some $N$) such that $d(x_m,x_n)<\epsilon$ for all $m,n>N$. If the sequence is Cauchy, you are guaranteed to win the challenge. Cauchy chose the letter $\epsilon$ to stand for *error* (or *erreur*): the finite approximations $x_n$ will have an error of less than $\epsilon$ from some point on.

Comment: In the hyperreal setting mentioned by the OP, the difference can be smaller than every positive real number and still be nonzero.  See my answer.

Comment: The question did not originally mention hyperreals.

Comment: OK, I guess I am coming in late in the game.

Answer (score 4):

If $n >m \ge 1$ you have $d(x_n,x_m) < 10^{n-1}$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and $N$ such that $10^{N-1} < \epsilon$, then if $n,m \ge N$
we have $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$.

Note that the statement is for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that blah, blah, blah, and not
that there is some $N$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have blah, blah, blah.

The latter formulation would imply that the sequence is constant after some $N$.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion comes from "for every positive real number $\epsilon$". In fact you have to fix $\epsilon$ first when finding $N$.

Answer (score 1):

first of all it is not that all the distances are less than every positive number. given a positive number , one can find a stage after which any two terms are the given number close to each other.

The idea of a sequence converging to some point do not necessarily imply that the distance between two terms of the sequence become zero.
What it says is that, as $n$ becomes larger, the terms of the convergent sequence starts coming closer to the previous one in terms of distance,

e.g in a sequence $<1/n>$ the distance between 1 and 1/2 is 1/2, distance between 1/2 and 1/4 is 1/4 and so on.. now if you look at distance between 
any two terms after 1/2, it is always less 1/2, if you look at the terms after 1/100 the max distance between any to terms will be upto 1/100 and so on. So if the given positive number is 1/100, you can choose here $n_0=101$(rather anything bigger than it). whereas if you want distance to be less than 1/1000 say, then this $n_0$ wont work, so you will need $n_{0}=1001$ atleast. It does not depend on terms being rational or irrational.

Answer (score 1):

" I do not understand how all distances $d(x_m,x_n)$ will be less than all positive real numbers."

This is the key to your misunderstanding.  All distances can't be.

But for any real number no matter who small we can find an infinite number of distances smaller.  (So we could say all real numbers are bigger than an infinite number of the distances...)

Let's do an actual example.  Consider .9, .99, .999, etc.  ($a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n 9/10^i$).  This is a cauchy sequence that converges to 1.  Okay, 1 is not irrational.  But is that *really* where your misunderstanding lies?  Okay, I'll get to that later.  But for now.

Cauchy sequence: for any $\epsilon > 0$  ... okay, let's say $\epsilon = 1/1,000,000$ ... we can find a point after which all distances are less than $\epsilon$ ... okay, that'd be simply $n > 7$. $ d(.99999\ldots9, .9999\ldots9) < 1/1,000,000$ for any two $.999\ldots99$ with more than 7 digits.

Okay, but let's make $\epsilon$ *really* small.  Let's make it 1/googol.  ($10^{-100}$)  Well, now if n > 100 we *still* have $(.999\ldots9, .9999\ldots) < 1/\text{googol}$ if those terms have more that 100 nines.  How about a googleplex?  Then the terms need a googol nines to be that close.  But we can find them with more than a googol nines.  No matter how small we can find a point where the following difference of terms is smaller.

That's a cauchy sequence.

Okay, that was a cauchy sequence of rational numbers converging to a rational number.  You wanted to know about a cauchy sequence of rational numbers converging to an irrational number and you suggested the decimal expansion of $\pi$.  Well, same thing.  $\pi$ expanded to a million decimal places will be off but it'll be of by a very small amount.  For *any* real number no matter how small, we can find a point after which all decimal expansions are closer that that to $\pi$.  These expansions are still finite but they are long enough to be closer to $\pi$ than the small real number we chose.  (And if they aren't, we simply choose the finite decimal expansions that *are* further out.  There'll always be finite expansions further out.  That's the point.)

It's true we never get there. And we can't really choose rational values that *can* get there (that's why the number is irrational). but we've trapped and honed it in with cauchy sequences.

Comment: thanks for your response. My main confusion has been made clear that you have to choose $\epsilon$ first and then you get $N$. But how does this work with infinitesimal (hyperreals)...How does this definition of completeness apply there ?

Comment: hyperreals are outside my area of expertise.  My understanding though is that cauchy sequences of reals do not nesc converge to hyperreals.  Hyperreals are not archimedian (for any x>0 y you can find integer n s.t. (n-1)x <= y < nx) and so have a different definition of completeness.  I really don't know.  I'm sorry I don't know more.  But the key of the reals is that epsilon of choice is *not* an infintisimal.

Comment: To say that the fact that "we never get there" is "why they are irrational" is nonsense.  The sequence $0.3,\ 0.33,\ 0.333,\ 0.3333,\ \ldots$ approaches $1/3$ and never gets there, but $1/3$ is rational. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yeah, I said that badly.  And it wasn't actually what I meant.  I meant we can't "get there" rather then "don't" get there.  i.e. we can't have *any* cauchy sequences where "the distances" get less then any positive real numbers.e.g. .3, .33 .333 or my .9, .99 can be replaced with 1/3, 1/3... where the "distances" can be all 0 which is "all these distances" are "less than all positive reals".  It was a vague statement but it was primarily meant for colloquialism and style rather than for rigor.

Comment: @fleablood, Terry Tao talks about a more generalized notion he calls a "hyperlimit" and then a sequence of reals can have a hyperreal as a hyperlimit.

Comment: Similarly, the sequence $0.3,\ 0.33,\ 0.333,\ 0.3333,\ \ldots$ will have a third as a limit but a hyperreal strictly smaller than though infinitely close to a third as a hyperlimit. @MichaelHardy

Comment: @user72694 Interesting.  As I said, outside my expertise.  I'd have to know what a hyper limit means and in what sense the reals are incomplete.  I guess it's a matter of "smaller than all numbers"?   There *does* exist a number that is closest to but not equal to a real?  Outside my area, but fascinating.

Comment: A question that came up in another post which I simply can't wrap my head around is how can the hyper/surreal numbers be considered an ordered field if it has a smallest strictly positive element e>0?  By ordered field properties,  for a>1 e>0 then e > e/a > 0.  Any ideas @user72694

Comment: @fleablood, great question.  The answer is, it doesn't.  This e is not the smallest element and of course in a field you couldn't have a smallest element.  As a first approximation think of a sequence tending to zero as generating an infinitesimal, e.g., $\frac{1}{n})$.  Then its square will be so much smaller: $\frac{1}{n^2}$.  More details can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602977/whats-an-example-of-an-infinitesimal/1602994#1602994

Comment: Hmm, I had gotten the impression that in the surreals (about which I know nothing) that there was a greatest element $\omega$ and that 1/$\omega$ = $\epsilon$ was therefore a smallest.   Others claimed it was an equivalency class and not a single element and ... I didn't have any idea.

Comment: @fleablood : This is not about surreal numbers, but about Robinson's hyperreal numbers.  An infinitesimal $\varepsilon>0$ is smaller than all reciprocals of finite integers, and hence smaller than all positive real numbers, but it is certainly not a smallest positive hyperreal number, since $\varepsilon/2$ is smaller, and so is $\varepsilon^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Fair 'nuff.... *but*..... If we *do* talk about surreal numbers, I have heard that 1) the surreals are on ordered field (although technically not a set) and 2) the surreals do have a least positive.  If the hyperreals don't have a smallest positive, I'm happy.  Ecstatic even.  But that just puts off the question until later.  How can the surreals by an ordered field with a smallest positive element.  (Although I suspect the real question is what the heck does "the surreals have a least positive element" actually mean and is it even true.)

Comment: @fleablood, the maximal (class) surreal field has been shown to be isomorphic to the similar hyperreal field, so there couldn't be the difference you mentioned.

Comment: So when I read that "the surreal numbers have an elemen't epsilon that is the lowest positive"  and  ... what?  I'm being lied to?  (from wikipedia "The only infinities in Sω are ω and -ω; but there are other non-real numbers in Sω among the reals. Consider the smallest positive number in Sω:" and there is this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593008/why-is-epsilon-not-a-rational-number

Comment: @fleablood : Why don't you post your question about the surreals as a separate question?  It's really rather remote from the topic of this question.

Comment: Other people have posted the question or similar questions and either I didn't understand the answers or they weren't satisfactory.  And I don't really care (at least not to the point where I can argue from a knowlegable basis).  Yes, this is off topic but as this is the comments section of an answer that I posted I don't feel it's damaging.  But we don't have to go on.

Answer (score -1):

I looked over the existing answers and they don't seem to address the concern of the OP as I understood it, so I will try to provide a separate answer.  The point is that the $(\epsilon,N)$-type definition of convergence is a first-order property and therefore by the transfer principle is still satisfied over the hyperreals.  More specifically, a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ will have a natural extension defined even for infinite values of the index $n$.  This extended sequence will satisfy the condition you mentioned, namely for every $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ such that, etc.  If epsilon is infinitesimal then as you point out $N$ will have to be infinite typically.

Having said this, the definition in question is provably equivalent to the one mentioned by other editors (and that involves fewer quantifiers), namely if both indices are infinite then the difference $x_n-x_m$ will be infinitesimal.